# Looking for a free alternative to Authy 2FA for desktop. Windows and Mac

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Looking for a free alternative to Authy 2FA for desktop. Windows and Mac. Authy for desktop will not be available as of March 18th and I am looking for a good reputable alternative that is free. For both Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) supports TOTP 2FA in version 2.2.0 and above. It's free and open source, supporting Windows, macOS, and Linux.