# Cross-platform 2FA that doesn't always require a phone

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I've been using Authy for many years as a 2FA, assured that if I ever lost my phone, the secrets would be synced to my desktop. Now that they're sunsetting the desktop app, I have no reason to stick to them, and am looking for an alternative.

Ideally it would have the following features:

- Cross-platform, where you only need one platform to access the secrets (so 2FAS is out)
- Secrets are synchronized automatically
- Secrets can be exported

I'm trying not to go back to Google Authenticator, in case I'm locked out of Google itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know whether this is working for a phone as well but did you see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/89965/looking-for-a-free-alternative-to-authy-2fa-for-desktop-windows-and-mac

Comment: Thanks! That app sadly doesn't have a native Android option